# Measuring execution time using Micrometer and WebFlux

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor, micrometer, spring-micrometer

I'd like to measure the length of some async calls made with WebFlux. I've been reading through various sources, as I understand the `@Timed` annotation is working with AspectJ and basically just starts a timer before the method call and stops it after. This obviously won't work with async methods.

Are there any solutions for WebFlux or the only thing I can do is passing around execution timestamps, cluttering my application logic?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Project Reactor natively supports Micrometer, please refer to the documentation to find out more:
https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/milestone/reference/#_publisher_metrics

For example, you may want to monitor `reactor.flow.duration`.